# PHP & MySQL empty records

Tags: php, mysql, get, http-status-code-404

In my database I've been getting individual records that are displayed by its own ID. In the URL is like this: `site.com/index.php?id=1`.  But if I write the address with an ID that does not exist *(like `site.com/index.php?id=3553255`)* it sends me to the page i use as "template", but with no data (an empty page).

**How could I send a header status 404, if the record is empty or does not exist?**

This is my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

$id = mysql_escape_string($_GET['d']);

include 'mysql_conexion.php';

$sql=" SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE id='$id'";
$data=mysql_query($sql,$conexion);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
      $id=$row['id'];
      $heading=$row['heading'];
 }

echo "<div><h1>$heading</h1></div>";

}

mysql_free_result($data); 
mysql_close($conexion);

?>
```

*Note:* I tried with else and header function
"else {header ('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);} exit;"  and header: location, 
but did not work.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You should print anything before the call to `header()` that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try inputting a simple if statement that basically looks something like this :

```
$numberofRows = count($cars);

if ($numberofRows == 0){

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />';

}

else{
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
      $id=$row['id'];
      $heading=$row['heading'];
 }

echo "<div><h1>$heading</h1></div>";

}

mysql_free_result($data); 
mysql_close($conexion);
}
?>
```

This will use your query to see how many rows match it. If the number is 0 it will redirect the user to what ever url is you 404 page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Misread use the same code provided just do this procedure before your html <header></header>. Inside the if echo the title you would like.